# WL.Clinet.connect - throwing error - CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

MFP Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180220-083852
MFP Client Vesion: 8.0.2018080605

I have an app which is using requireJS, backbone & jquery.
I am loading the main js like this:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require/require.js"></script>
```

I am making sure the call to main.js is made inside wlCommoninit. The app is loaded with all dependencies.

```
  function wlCommoninit(){
      main();     // main.js has a single method named - main 
  }
```

I have a call to "WL.Client.connect" @ the end of main function- which just executes & does nothing.

A subsequent call to "WL.Client.connect" returns the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to Worklight Server: 

              {"responseHeaders":{},
                   "responseText":"undefined",
                   "errorCode":"CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS"}
```

What could be the reason for the above error? Though we make a call to WL.Client.connect inside wlcommoninit. Hopefully all the WL API would have loaded by the time 'wlCommoninit' is invoked.

Tired with different MFP clinet sdk versions other that mentioned above. I don't see any change.

Comment: My scenario may seem to be of less details. To the point .. 
function wlCommoninit(){
     WL.Client.connect({
  onSuccess : successCallBack,
 onFailure : failureCallBack
      });    
  }
In the above call - no call back is triggered. neither success nor failure. 
Down the lane in the code - If I invoke WL.Client.connect  again - I see following error -"errorCode":"CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS"
 What could be the reason. I have checked following
   App is registered to local MFP 8 server
   Version of the App in Config.xml matches - the one on console. Did i miss any other check here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the response

```
{"responseHeaders":{},"responseText":"undefined","errorCode":"CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS"}
```

is that before the first WL.Client.connect() succeeds or fails, you have fired another connect() call.

Wait until the first succeeds, fails or times out from inactivity.